# Templates using only front end (html, js, css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, extends

First time posting on stackoverflow!

I am wondering if there is a way to use templates, and especially something similar to this:

```
{% extends "./templates/base.html" %}
```

only using FRONT-END (no server side) to create a webapp with multiple pages, all of them extending a base template.

Comment: Just google for "frontend templating engine". Should be plenty of results.

Comment: You can use the same css styles on all html pages, make header with menu and footer as separate html pages and include it on top and bottom of page with php, php is server side but it will generate html page and send it to client

Comment: You may take a look at Handlebars.js

Comment: @PavelBeresnev OP says specifically `only using FRONT-END`.

Comment: @PavelBeresnev "php is server side but it will generate html page and send it to client", yes of course it will, that's what all server-side languages do (amongst other things).

Comment: @ChrisG thanks a lot I found the solution thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Chris G gave me a good lead. Because english is not my first language, my google queries were not leading anywhere. After using exactly what Chris said, i found [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-modularize-html-using-template-engines-and-gulp-d1cb8af54138) answering my question. Cheers and thanks to everyone that helped!